# NameError: name 'Right' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, nameerror

I'm trying to execute the following code in Spyder 3.3.1 using Python 2.7.15. I'm a beginner.

```
  text = str(input("You are lost in forest..."))
  while text == "Right":
      text = str(input("You are lost in forest..."))
  print "You got out of the forest!!!"
```

When I run the code with integer value it works. For example the following piece of code:

```
  text = input("You are lost in forest...")
  while text == 1:
      text = input("You are lost in forest...")
  print "You got out of the forest!!!"
```

How can I make the input() work with a string value? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
value = raw_input("You are lost in forest...") # String input 
value = int(raw_input("You are lost in forest...")) # Integer input 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2, `raw_input()` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string. `input()` tries to understand the data entered by the user.Hence expects a syntactically correct python statement.That's why you got an error when you enter `Right`. So you can enter `"Right"` as input to fix this error.

But it is better to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.